# GridView is not showing the background color for each row when the condition hits?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Following code is used for the **`background colour`** for the each row , when the condition `if (cellValue != "TALLIED")` hits, the background colour is not changing to red.

page.aspx Code for GridView

```
 <div class="legend">Currency Rate</div>
                 <div class="t-col t-col-12 text-right margin-10-0 t-clearfix padding-0">
                     <div class="t-col t-col-12 padding-0-5">
                         <div class="responsive-table">
                             <asp:GridView ID="grdView2" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Ref"
                                 AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%" AllowPaging="False" CssClass="mydatagrid dt-responsive grvCRM" 
                                 PagerStyle-CssClass="pager"
                                 HeaderStyle-CssClass="header" RowStyle-CssClass="rows" OnRowDataBound="grdView2_RowDataBound"
                                 EmptyDataText="No Record Found" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True">
                                 <Columns>
                                     <asp:BoundField DataField="Ref" HeaderText="Ref No" />
                                     <asp:BoundField DataField="Curr" HeaderText="Currency" />
                                     <asp:BoundField DataField="Bal" HeaderText="Teller Balance" />
                                     <asp:BoundField DataField="EXSH" HeaderText="Excess Shortage" />
                                 </Columns>
                                 <EmptyDataRowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                 <HeaderStyle CssClass="header" />
                                 <PagerStyle CssClass="pager" />
                                 <RowStyle CssClass="rows" />
                                 <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="row-alt" />
                             </asp:GridView>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
```

page.aspx.cs code

```
protected void btnView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    DataSet Datatable1 = new DataSet();
    Datatable1 = getExcessShortageDEtails();
    if (Datatable1.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0 && Datatable1.Tables[0] != null)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt64(Datatable1.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Ref"]) > 0)
        {
            grdView2.DataSource = Datatable1.Tables[0];
            grdView2.DataBind();
        }
    }
 }
 

     protected void grdView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
         {
             if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
             {
                 int columnIndex = 4; 
                 string cellValue = Convert.ToString(e.Row.Cells[columnIndex].Text);
                 if (cellValue != "TALLIED")
                 {
                     e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                 }
             }
         }
```

SQL SIDE : here 3 values are there **EXCESS , SHORTAGE AND TALLIED** ,
only TALLIED with normal other with Different Colour i.e., I mention is RED

```
  SQL SIDE

CREATE TABLE CurrencyRate (
    Ref NVARCHAR(50),
    Curr NVARCHAR(50),
    Bal DECIMAL(10, 2),
    EXSH NVARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO CurrencyRate (Ref, Curr, Bal,EXSH) VALUES (1,'USD', 50, 'EXCESS');
INSERT INTO CurrencyRate (Ref, Curr, Bal,EXSH) VALUES (2,'AED', 100, 'EXCESS');
INSERT INTO CurrencyRate (Ref, Curr, Bal,EXSH) VALUES (3,'EUR', 50, 'SHORTAGE');
INSERT INTO CurrencyRate (Ref, Curr, Bal,EXSH) VALUES (4,'INR', 600, 'TALLIED');
```

Comment: best guess is you are using templated columns. In that case, you can't use the cells[] collection, but have to use find control to get/grab the control for that GV row. Post a bit or some of your markup used for the GV, and that will give us the information here to resolve this issue. Your code looks fine, but we need to see the GV markup to be sure here.

Comment: Did you check what the actual value is of `cellValue`?

Comment: @VDWWD, at the Cell value the value is getting true, and it is entering to the if loop but the the grid is not reflecting the color

Comment: Well, then you have to post your markup of the GV, and you have to post the code you using to load the GV.  Without a reproducible example, we really can't help you much. So, edit your post, include the markup, and your code that loads the GV. That way, we have a proof of concept here to work from.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal, i Updated the Question with the required as you mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See, this is often why we ask for some of the markup.

I saw the answer in less then 4 seconds of my time.

You have a row style of this:

```
 RowStyle-CssClass="rows"
```

So, keep in mind there are 2 ways to set the background color.

You can use "background", or use "background-color" in the style.

Turns out that if you set both, then "background-color" is the color that is used. In fact it is the LAST color setting that is used.

So, we could with code "remove" the style from the row, but most simple is then to use "style" and "over ride" the current "background-color" setting.

Hence this should work:

replace this:

```
 e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;  (bad)
```

with:

```
 e.Row.Style.Add("background-color", "Red");
```

As noted, you could consider blanking out the style, but, using above background-color will overwrite the existing "background-color" you have, and if a existing background-color style exists, then it will be replaced with the above code.

So, with both a background-color setting, and a background setting, the background-color setting will be used, since it is the last setting  you have set.

Comment: Thanks working for me, thanks Albert D. Kallal,for your support.